# Segmentation fault in Z3

Tags: z3

I am working on a benchmark with Quantified BitVector formulas with bit-vector arithmetic. The benchmark produces with Z3 4.3.0 a segmentation fault in Linux 64 bit. I think the problem occurs because of a transitive use of equality.

```
...
(assert (= (bvadd (capacity this) (_ bv1 5)) (EAO.length (elements this))  ))
(assert (= (EAO.length (elements this)) (IKAO.length (heap this)) ))
```

The complete benchmark in question can be found here:
[example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/ASf2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the crash. [I fixed the bug](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/bdc675b1dfef). The fix is already available in the unstable (working-in-progress) branch. [Here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) are instructions on how to build the unstable branch. The fix will also be available tomorrow in the Z3 nightly builds.

The nightly build can be downloaded at: http://z3.codeplex.com/releases. We have to click at the "Planned" link. I wrote some instructions [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html).